# Merging Dataframe with Different Dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I want to merge a seperate dataframe (df2) with the main dataframe (df1), but if, for a given row, the dates in df1 do not exist in df2, then search for the recent date before the underlying date in df1.

I tried to use pd.merge, but it would remove rows with unmatched dates, and only keep the rows that matched in both df's.

```
df1 = [['2007-01-01','A'],
       ['2007-01-02','B'],
       ['2007-01-03','C'],
       ['2007-01-04','B'],
       ['2007-01-06','C']]

df2 = [['2007-01-01','B',3],
       ['2007-01-02','A',4],
       ['2007-01-03','B',5],
       ['2007-01-06','C',3]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df1[0] = pd.to_datetime(df1[0])
df2[0] = pd.to_datetime(df2[0])
```

**Current df1 | pd.merge():**

```
    0           1   2
0   2007-01-06  C   3
```

Only gets the exact date between both df's, it does not consider value from recent dates.

**Expected df1:**

```
    0           1   2
0   2007-01-01  A   NaN
1   2007-01-02  B   3
2   2007-01-03  C   NaN
3   2007-01-04  B   3
4   2007-01-06  C   3
```

Getting NaNs because data doesn't exist on or before that date in df2. For index row 1, it gets data before a day before, while index row 4, it gets data exactly on the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you output by using `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on=0,by=1,allow_exact_matches=True)
Out[15]: 
           0  1    2
0 2007-01-01  A  NaN
1 2007-01-02  B  3.0
2 2007-01-03  C  NaN
3 2007-01-04  B  5.0 # here should be 5 since 5 ' date is more close. also df2 have two B 
4 2007-01-06  C  3.0
```

Comment: Amazing! You are very talented. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using your merge code, which I assume you have since its not present in your question, insert the argument `how=left` or `how=outer`.

It should look like this:

```
dfmerged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['Date'], right_on=['Date'])
```

You can then use slicing and renaming to keep the columns you wish.

```
dfmerged = dfmerged[['Date', 'Letters', 'Numbers']]
```

Note: I do not know your column names since you haven't shown any code. Substitute as necessary

Comment: I don't get the same expected df, I'm not sure if you understood my problem